# Read CVS file and ouput the CSV file to .txt file

Tags: php, csv

Hi here I am reading a CSV file and I am trying to write the CSV file data into a .txt file.

```
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die ("unable to open file");
                fwrite($myfile, $data[$c]);
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
}
```

The newfile.txt are being created and only the last record in the CSV file are showing in the newfile.txt. Can anyone tell me why everything in the CSV are not showing in my newfile.txt(only the last record are displaying). Thank You

Comment: That's maybe because it rewrite the same line. Try to put all the string together and fwrite only one big string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to open the new file once.

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) && $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w")) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        fputcsv($myfile, $data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your file with `a+` parameter instead of `w` for `fopen`.

From [the doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fopen.php), the mode 'w' opens for writing only, while the mode 'a+' opens for reading and writing and place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, it attempts to create it.

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "a+") or die ("unable to open file");
            fwrite($myfile, $data[$c]);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are opening the file on every loop iteration which not a good idea try putting it above the loop
2. Use **a+** mode instead of **w** in the fopen [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Answer (score 1):

this is probably because you reopen your textfile everytime you write a record and overwrite its content. Either open the file in append mode (can't tell you how, I am not a php programmer) or open your textfile only once and write several times in one session.

Edit: You should use 'a' or 'a+' instead of 'w' as parameter for fopen as explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php